# Add to a stack across classes in Android App

Tags: java, android, stack

I want to add to a stack in one of my android fragments from other classes.  I'm trying to call methods inside the initial class to push, pop, and peek a stack that was created in `OnCreate()`. It's easy to call methods from outside classes if the method is static.  A static method it seems would require me to instantiate a new stack to use each time the method is called, and I want to just add in the same stack each time.

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this problem, but my only idea on how to solve it is to pass a stack all around my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a singleton that would manage your stack.

It would look something like this:

```
public class StackManager {

    private static StackManager ourInstance = new StackManager();
    public Stack myStack = new Stack();

    public static StackManager getInstance() {
         return ourInstance;
    }

    private StackManager() {
    }
}
```

To Access your stack:

```
StackManager.getInstance().myStack
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to singletons!